# Getting areas the closest from markers

Tags: google-maps

I've got some question but I'm not even sure how to explain it. I'll give a try.
I'm trying to make a map where there are several markers (bus stops) and I'd like to have areas representing for each marker a circle area covering the map so that you could see what is your closest marker.
This means that if 2 markers are close enough (are if the circles are wide enough) they won't superpose, there will be a line between them.

I don't know if its clear but I don't even know where to start. I guess this matrix must have a name but I dont know what.

Thanks for your help.

Edit: I found out there was a name to what I was looking for. It's the Voronoi diagram. J3.js deals with it quite well.

Comment: If you can't explain it maybe a sketch of the problem makes it more understandable.

Comment: Check DistanceMatrix, Directions and Geocoding. I'm not sure if circle is good hint for distance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out what I was looking for was a Voronoi diagram.
With a little bit of JS I'll be able to achieve my goal: http://strongriley.github.io/d3/ex/voronoi.html